# Symfony : Error 500, cache clear on production?

Tags: caching, module, ftp, symfony-1.4

I suddenly can't access a module on my website, it is giving me an Error 500 and I don't know why (I also don't have access to the error log). It was working well earlier.

I thought that it could have been because of a file I replaced earlier on the FTP server, so I retransfered previous versions of all the files related to that module onto the FTP server again. The module is still giving me an Error 500 at the moment.

I am now thinking that clearing the cache on production could fix the problem. What do you think?

I am working on a copy of the original website on WAMP and therefore can't delete the production cache from the command line. Is deleting all the content of the `/cache/` folder from the FTP server the same thing? What risks does it represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearing the cache manually by FTP won't harm anything unless you developed something specific that stores important files in this folder.

Comment: If you put anything important in the `cache` folder, which cannot be easily regenerated, then there is a special name for your idea ;) You can safely delete all the contents of the cache as it will be regenerated. Basically the symfony `cache:clear` task does the same thing.

Comment: Thank you, I cleared my cache manually and it fixed the problem I had!